# Obtaining process CPU usage

Tags: java, multithreading, process, cpu-usage, jmx

I have a program that loads a text file holding some information and based on that information it runs multiple thread. Each thread is a process. Here is my code:

```
public class runMultiClient {
public static void main(String[] args){
    List<Process> PRlist = new ArrayList<Process>();
    List<String[]> commandsList = new ArrayList<String[]>();
    boolean running = true;

    if (args.length == 2 && args[0].matches("-f")){
        String dir = System.getProperty("user.dir");
        String path = dir + "/" + args[1];
        FileReader fr;
        try {
            fr = new FileReader(path);
            BufferedReader bf = new BufferedReader(fr);

            String line = "";
            while ((line = bf.readLine()) != null){
                String[] tk = line.split(" ");
                String[] cmd = {"java", "-jar", "Client.jar", "-a", tk[0], "-p", tk[1],
                        "-u", tk[2], "-pw", tk[3], "-m", tk[4], "-s", tk[5]};
                Process pr = new ProcessBuilder().inheritIO().command(cmd).start();
                PRlist.add(pr);
                commandsList.add(cmd);
                System.out.println(tk[4] + " streaming process is established.");
            }
        } 
        catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {ex.printStackTrace();} 
        catch (IOException ex) {ex.printStackTrace();}
    } else {
        System.out.println("No stream file was specified.");
    }
}}
```

Inside my `Client.jar` file, i have a variable that monitors the cpu load of that class:

```
OperatingSystemMXBean osBean = ManagementFactory.getPlatformMXBean(OperatingSystemMXBean.class);
            cpuLoad = osBean.getProcessCpuLoad();
```

Is there any way i can reach that variable from the `runMultiClient` class?
If not, is there any way of using the `OperatingSystemMXBean` on the running process? 
I have tried `pr.getClass()`, but it got me nowhere.
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you provide the complete class where that cpuLoad variable is located ?

Comment: I can, but how will it help you?

Comment: The `cpuLoad` is a public variable in the other class.

Answer (score 2):

## Option #1: Add agent library and expose JMX over HTTP

You can bundle [Jolokia](https://jolokia.org/features-nb.html) agent with your monitored application (another similar thing is [SimpleJMX](http://256stuff.com/sources/simplejmx/jmx_web_http.shtml). It exposes JMX beans over http/json so this works for interacting with JMX from other languages like python (and super comfy when troubleshooting from command like). After that you can access mbeans of your interest via apache http client or the like.

## Option #2: JMX client

allow remote connections by adding the following params when starting your monitored application:

```
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=9999 \
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false \
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false
```

Then you should be able to access the mbeans by jconsole and hand written JMX client code, like in [the tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jmx/remote/custom.html)

Comment: I dont need to monitor it from remote location. I just need the `runMultiClient` class to have access to that value which is calculated for the `Client`.

Comment: @DanyLavrov remote word here is just to highlight the fact that the caller does not reside in the same VM as the MBean. Your launcher process will communicate with your launches application via a tcp socket in this case.

Comment: @DanyLavrov if it is not in the same process, it's remote. Java doesn't use shared memory in general, which is what you would use otherwise.

Comment: So that means that for every sub-proccess there would be created a new JMX client, listening on a new socket?

Comment: @DanyLavrov yes, for every sub-process bundled JMX agent will be listening on a new socket. JMX clients is what connects to those sockets and retrieve info

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if you need to call `ProcessBuilder().inheritIO()` for some other requirement, but if not, you could start a daemon thread in your Client.jar process that periodically writes the cpu load to System.out. Then your runMultiClient thread[s] could read those from the InputStream representing the process's System.out.  Or, have the thread accept commands and print accordingly. Rough example:

Run this in the spawned Client.jar:

```
public static void startCmdListener() {
    try {
        Thread t = new Thread("CmdListener") {
            BufferedReader br = null;
            InputStreamReader isr = null;
            final OperatingSystemMXBean os = (OperatingSystemMXBean) ManagementFactoryHelper.getOperatingSystemMXBean();
            public void run() {
                try {
                    isr = new InputStreamReader(System.in);
                    br = new BufferedReader(isr);
                } catch (Exception ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace(System.err);
                    return;
                } 
                try {
                    String cmd = null;
                    while(true) {
                        cmd = br.readLine();
                        if("cpu".equalsIgnoreCase(cmd)) {   // cpu command, print the process load
                            System.out.println(os.getProcessCpuLoad());
                        } else if("exit".equalsIgnoreCase(cmd)) {   // exit command, break
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                } catch (Exception ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace(System.err);
                    return;
                } 

            }
        };
        t.setDaemon(true);
        t.start();
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace(System.err);
    }
}
```

Run this in the runMultiClient to get the cpu load:

```
public static double getCpu(OutputStream processIn, InputStream processOut) {
    PrintStream ps = null;
    BufferedReader br = null;
    InputStreamReader isr = null;

    try {
        ps = new PrintStream(processIn);
        isr = new InputStreamReader(processOut);
        br = new BufferedReader(isr);
        ps.println("cpu");
        ps.flush();         
        return Double.parseDouble(br.readLine());
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        throw new RuntimeException(ex);
    } finally {
        if(ps!=null) try { ps.close(); } catch (Exception x) {}
        if(br!=null) try { br.close(); } catch (Exception x) {}
        if(isr!=null) try { isr.close(); } catch (Exception x) {}
    }
}
```

Comment: That sound like a good work around. I think i will give it a try. thank you